# LangServe access POST data in path function fast api

Tags: python, fastapi, langchain

[Update (12/15/2023) from the LangServe maintainer](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langserve/discussions/327#discussioncomment-7865460)

My issue is less about coding and more of how things are done in Fast API. I'm not familiar with Fast API in relation to LangServe and the extreme abstractions going on with it.

Lemme use an explicit example using Django. When I send a POST request to a Django REST endpoint:

```
{
    'input': 'Input text',
    'history': 'My history text'
}
```

I can grab the individual fields on the payload via

```
class myAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        input = request.data.get('input')
        history = request.data.get('history')
        ....
```

It is THAT simple, and anybody, even a non-programmer reading that code can explicitly understand what's going on by just looking at it in a second. It's not ambiguous, it's obvious and just makes instant sense. No abstractions, no 'automagics' anywhere.

However, in this case, I'm sending the same payload to the LangServe default endpoint using the default template

This is the default template I'm using:

https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/tree/master/templates/rag-chroma-private

```
{
    'input': 'Input text',
    'history': 'My history text'
}
```

When I send the above to the langserve endpoint, 'Automagically', it knows to look for the `input` field and use it. But I want to be able to access other fields IN the POST request payload explicitly.

How do I do that?

Currently my langchain route is

```
...
# Edit this to add the chain you want to add
add_routes(app, rag_chroma_private_chain, path="/myendpoint")
```

I intend to access the `My history text` in my chain code.

How do I access the `<payload>.history` field in the langchain context?

Edit:

In other words, when I sent a frontend request, of say, `{ 'mymessage': 'message' }` to the `path="/myendpoint"` in LangServe, how do I access the `mymessage` field in the function?

LangServe "automagically" knows to look for the `input` field. If there are other fields, how do I access them?

Edit 3:

From [rag-chroma-private](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/templates/rag-chroma-private/rag_chroma_private/chain.py) langchain template, there's:

```
...
# RAG chain
chain = (
    RunnableParallel({"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()})
    | prompt
    | model
    | StrOutputParser()
)


# Add typing for input
class Question(BaseModel):
    __root__: str


chain = chain.with_types(input_type=Question)
```

And then in the `server.py` created via the [langchain cli](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/templates/README.md), there's this

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from langserve import add_routes
from rag_chroma_private import chain as rag_chroma_private_chain

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def redirect_root_to_docs():
    return RedirectResponse("/docs")

add_routes(app, rag_chroma_private_chain, path="/edu")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

If I want to send a payload of extra fields, other than the `input`, how do I access those extra fields?